# If the row of a matrix is divided by a scalar, is the determinent multiplied by the scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra

Right now I'm a bit confused by my textbook. Where my textbook defines that, when a row is multiplied by a scalar, then the determinant is also multiplied by a scalar
[textbook definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziuX7.png)
Where I am getting confused, is that [a youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2AtDIGic_0) that I am watching, and following gives me the correct answer is giving an opposite definition.
[Picture of Conflicting definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tred.png)

Following the youtube video's definition gives me the correct answer, but seems to be the exact opposite of the website's definition.[Example Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqDIk.jpg) where you can see that as I mulitply a row by a scalar (1/3), I multiply the determinant by (3) not (1/3), which gives me the correct answer.

Anyone know what am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: The definition in the textbook coincides with the definition in the picture. The definition in the picture is the method you use to find the determinant based on the theory from the book. i.e if $B=aA$ then $det(B)=adet(A)$ and hence if you know the determinant of $B$ and you want to find determinant of $A$, then you find it by dividing $det(B)$ by $a$. $det(A)=\frac{1}{a}det(B)$.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm thinking I understand this better. I think my textbook words this definition poorly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the row of a matrix is multiplied by a scalar, the determinant is also multiplied by that scalar.

The division you're seeing happens because, when we're finding the determinant of a matrix, we don't want it to change at all.

So you might write, for example, that 
$$
   \det \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix} =\frac1{100} \det \begin{bmatrix}100 & 200 \\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}.
$$
When we multiply the first row by $100$, we multiply the determinant by $100$, so we introduce a factor of $\frac1{100}$ to keep the overall expression the same.

This is equivalent to writing 
$$
   \det \begin{bmatrix}100 & 200 \\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix} = 100\det \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

No, you might want to check your work.

If you multiply a row in the matrix by $k$, the determinant is ALSO multiplied by $k$.

Your work also agrees with this.

Let your original matrix be A and your new matrix be B.

You said that $\det(A) = 3\det(B)$, that's the same thing as saying $\det(B) = \frac{1}{3}\det(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

- If you multiply a row of a matrix by a constant $k$ then the determinant of the new matrix is $k$ times the determinant of the old matrix.
- If when trying to calculate the determinant of the old matrix you divide a row by a constant $c \not= 0$ then the determinant of the old matrix is $c$ times the determinant of the new matrix.

These two statements are basically saying the same thing with $c = \frac1k$ and are consistent with each other.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is
$$
\det(a_1,\ldots,\lambda a_i,\ldots,a_n) = \lambda\det(a_1,\ldots,a_n).
$$
Hence,
$$
\det(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = c\cdot \det(a_1,\ldots,\frac 1ca_i,\ldots,a_n).
$$